# How to use third party plugin in rails 6? Using webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

How can I use the the third party plugin via webpacker. I dont want to use cloudfare external link in application.html.erb.

**Why means**, I just want to compile all the plugin while application loading for the initial time.

Thanks in advance :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title><%= yield(:title).present? ? yield(:title) : 'Tryblank' %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<%= yield(:description).present? ? yield(:description) : 'Tryblank' %>" />
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover" />
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.12/css/lightgallery.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.12/js/lightgallery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lg-thumbnail/1.1.0/lg-thumbnail.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%# <p class="notice"> notice</p> <p class="alert">alert</p> %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")

import '../stylesheets/style'
import './default.js' 
import './bootstrap_custom.js'
import './side_menu.js.erb'
//import './sweetalert.js'
import './business_hours.js'
import './admin.js'
import './services.js'
import './user_service.js'
```

Answer (score 3):

I answered a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58794513/12104222

There, I explained how to include jquery, bootstrap and popper.js to a project using `yarn`, and then two different approaches to actually importing the libraries (or modules) to use them in your app, depending on whether you need to expose the modules as a global plugin (something you probably want only for jQuery and similar global libraries) or not, as a single import (the most common option, which I exemplified with Bootstrap).

### Updated with instructions for sweetalert & lightgallery, as requested by OP:

1. Run `$ yarn sweetalert lightgallery lg-thumbnail` (or whatever plugins you may need; you can also use `yarn sweetalert@2.1.2`, etc if you need a specific version of the plugin). That will install the modules in your `node_modules` directory, and will make them available to Webpacker.
   You will also need `$ yarn jquery` to install jquery as a node module as well.
2. Edit your config/webpack/environment.js so it looks like this:

```
# Some other previous code

environment.plugins.append('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

That will ensure jQuery is exposed to every other plugin that depends on it.

4. Edit app/javascript/packs/application.js so it looks like this:

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
//require("jquery") //commented as you loaded jQuery before.

import '../stylesheets/style'
import './default.js' 
import './bootstrap_custom.js'
import './side_menu.js.erb'
import swal from 'sweetalert' //Note you don't need './' in your path if you import via yarn
import 'lightgallery'
import './business_hours.js'
import './admin.js'
import './services.js'
import './user_service.js'
```

4. Import lightGallery.css in your application.scss
5. Remove these lines from your view, since you will be loading them using webpack:

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.12/css/lightgallery.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.12/js/lightgallery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lg-thumbnail/1.1.0/lg-thumbnail.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

By now, you've installed jQuery, lightgallery and sweetalert as webpack modules. I cannot guarantee, however, that this will work in your case since the code you provided looks like it's importing a lot of different plugins from many different sources (webpack, CDN, maybe also sprockets) which can (and probably will) cause conflicts between them. 
If possible, I'd recommend you replace every `<script>` tag with the correct import method for webpack, which is just following the method I described for the plugins you mentioned in this answer, but applying them to your other libraries/plugins.

Edit 2:
Remember that, if you use Turbolinks (and it looks like you do), you need to replace this sort of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#lightgallery").lightGallery(); 
    });
```

With this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
        $("#lightgallery").lightGallery(); 
    });
```

Good luck!

Comment: Can you please explain more about this. Because I don't know how to import sweetalert and lightgallery in environment.js .

Comment: Updated my answer as per your request

Comment: very sorry for the late reply. ReferenceError: Swal is not defined. I followed your every steps. But still I'm facing this issue

Comment: This is a great post. Which directory is being referred to in the directive ```import './bootstrap_custom.js'```?

Comment: Got it all working except that the CSS is requiring some fonts that I don't from where and how to import. The path is '/fonts/lg.woff2' and I get this error 'application.scss:4 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../fonts/lg.woff2?io9a6k''